# Deal array to function arguments

Tags: matlab, vectorization, anonymous-function

I have a function (created through the symbolic toolbox) that takes a number of scalar inputs:

```
scalarFn = @(a,b,c) a .* b + c
```

I would like to alter this function so that it instead takes a single input and deals the elements of a vector to the input arguments of the function above:

```
vectorFn = @(theta) theta(1) .* theta(2) + theta(3)
```

I've played around with `deal` and or combining `num2cell` with `{:}` indexing but I haven't figured out how to compose this function yet.

Ultimately, I want a function that takes a function handle like `scalarFn` (but not necessarily having only 3 arguments - quite likely more) and gives back a new function handle `vectorFn` that has only one input as a vector. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: are you saying that vectorFn  isn't working for you?

Comment: See edit. I'm working with general function handles here.

Comment: Are you ok with `theta` being a cell array (`{a, b, c}`), or must it be a numeric vector (`[a, b, c]` with `a`, `b` `c` scalars)? Also, must `vectorFn` be defined as an anonymous function (i.e. single statement), or can it be defined in a file?

Comment: I'd be fine with `vectorFn` being defined in a file. But `theta` does need to be a numeric vector of `[a b c]`.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I found a more intelligent way to use the symbolic toolbox (using the `Vars` argument of `matlabFunction`) as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a clunky answer, I know I can do it with an `eval` statement:

```
vectorFn = eval(['@(theta) scalarFn(' strjoin(arrayfun(@(x) ['theta(' num2str(x) ')'], 1:nargin(scalarFn), 'Uniform', false), ', ') ')']);

scalarFn(1,2,3)
vectorFn([1 2 3])
```

But this seems to be a particularly not robust solution.